# Object method call inside WebSocket's 'onopen()' function gives 'Function is undefined'

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am trying to write a ChatClient based on JavaScript and want to call some other object methods inside 'onopen' or 'onmessage' functions like 'this.some()'. What's wrong?

```
var ChatClient = function() {

    this.me = null; // This user

    this.others = []; // Other users

    this.socket = null;

    this.handshake = function() {

        this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + "localhost" + ":8000");

        // Error occurred
        this.socket.onerror = function(error) {

            console.log('Socket error: ' + error);
        };

        // Opened
        this.socket.onopen = function() {

            console.log('Socket opened');

            this.some(); // <== Error: this.some is undefined
        };

        // Message received
        this.socket.onmessage = function(message) {

            console.log('Socket message: ' + message.data);
        };

        // Closed
        this.socket.onclose = function(message) {

            console.log('Socket message: ' + message.data);
        };
    };

    this.someOther = function() {

        alert('name');
    }

    this.some = function() {

        this.someOther();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access `this` inside the asynchronous call which will not be present when socket will be open. And this cause this.some() to be undefined.

Below code should work:

```
var ChatClient = function() {

    var _self = this; // Save outer context
    this.me = null; // This user
    this.others = []; // Other users

    this.socket = null;

    this.handshake = function() {

        this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + "localhost" + ":8000");

        // Error occurred
        this.socket.onerror = function(error) {

            console.log('Socket error: ' + error);
        };

        // Opened
        this.socket.onopen = function() {

            console.log('Socket opened');

            _self.some(); //It should work
        };

        // Message received
        this.socket.onmessage = function(message) {

            console.log('Socket message: ' + message.data);
        };

        // Closed
        this.socket.onclose = function(message) {

            console.log('Socket message: ' + message.data);
        };
    };

    this.someOther = function() {

        alert('name');
    }

    var some = function() {

        this.someOther();
    }
}
```

The problem in the way you are calling this.some() is that the reference of `this` has already been changed from the context of `ChatClient` to `WebSocket.open` method. Stll if you wan to use the outer context you need to store the context in some variable.eg: _this or self;

```
var _self = this;
```

And then use _self.some to call the outer functions or variables.

PS: Edited the answer please check :)

Comment: Yes I can accept this reason. But I can set the variable 'me' inside the 'onmessge' how it's possible?

Comment: You need to remember this  in that case. 

`var _self = this;`


And then use `_self` instead of this to get the access of the variables.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But Do I really need to pack the webSocket creation inside a try catch block?

Comment: I don't know much about WebSocket working. But if it seems to be throwing the error at any point in future and you know what you can do if an error will occur. Put it in try catch :)