# method undefined in ES6 class on websocket message recieved

Tags: javascript, websocket, ecmascript-6

I get following message when websocket event fired. not able to access outer context object.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wsHandler' of undefined
>       at WebSocket.onmessage_recieved (clsWebSocketSender.js:42)

```
class WebSocketSender
{
    constructor(wsHandler)
    {
        var _self=this;        
        this.wsHandler=wsHandler;
        this.ws==null;      
        this.url='';
    }

    intialize(url,sender)
    {
        this.url=url;
        this.ws = new WebSocket(url);  
        this.ws.onopen=()=>console.log("opened");    
        this.ws.onclose=()=>console.log("closed");                        
        this.ws.onerror=()=>console.log("error");
        this.ws.addEventListener('message',this.onmessage_recieved);
    }

    send(data)
    {
        if(this.ws.readyState==1)
        {            
            this.ws.send(data);
        }
    }

    onmessage_recieved(e)
    {
        debugger;
        var server_message = e.data;
        let jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        this._self.wsHandler.onMessageReceived(jsonData)
    }

    close()
    {
        if(this.ws.readyState==1)
        {
            this.ws.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function for callbacks: change *onmessage_recieved* method to:

```
onmessage_recieved = (e) => {
    debugger;
    var server_message = e.data;
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
    this.wsHandler.onMessageReceived(jsonData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access it via `_self`, a variable local to the constructor:

`var _self=this;`

Try accessing it directly on `this` instead:

`this.wsHandler.onMessageReceived(jsonData)`

If you then get an issue with `this` being undefined or something other than you expect it to be (which I expect you will), simply change your event listener to use an arrow function, this will preserve your `this`.

`this.ws.addEventListener('message', (message) => this.onmessage_recieved(message));`

---

```js
class WebSocketSender {
  constructor(wsHandler) {
    this.wsHandler = wsHandler;
    this.ws == null;
    this.url = '';
  }
  intialize(url, sender) {
    this.url = url;
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    this.ws.onopen = () => console.log("opened");
    this.ws.onclose = () => console.log("closed");
    this.ws.onerror = () => console.log("error");
    this.ws.addEventListener('message', message => this.onmessage_recieved(message));
  }
  send(data) {
    if (this.ws.readyState == 1) {
      this.ws.send(data);
    }
  }
  onmessage_recieved(e) {
    debugger;
    var server_message = e.data;
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
    this.wsHandler.onMessageReceived(jsonData)
  }
  close() {
    if (this.ws.readyState == 1) {
      this.ws.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The major differences here are:

`this.ws.addEventListener('message', this.onmessage_recieved);`

The WebSocket will invoke `onmessage_recieved` and pass itself as `this`

`this.ws.addEventListener('message', message => this.onmessage_recieved(message));`

The arrow function will preserve `this` and ignore whatever the WebSocket passes as `this`

Comment: tried still same error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMessageReceived' of undefined
    at WebSocket.onmessage_recieved (clsWebSocketSender.js:42)

Comment: Then are you sure `wsHandler` is being passed into the constructor as expected?

Comment: yes its initialized. I think scope is different when event fired from websocket.

Comment: Using the arrow function should solve that issue:
`this.ws.addEventListener('message', (message) => this.onmessage_recieved(message));`

Comment: I think this will work as defined in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530305/object-method-call-inside-websockets-onopen-function-gives-function-is-und?rq=1 
but how to implement in es6 class

Comment: I believe it is the same problem, but slapping `self = this` everywhere is not the right way to go about it. You have to understand why you have this problem and why `self = this` solves it. Many people think `this` is a mysterious beast that should just be ignored - but it's really quite simple. You should have no problems using the ES6 arrow function - can you confirm my WHOLE code snippet still gives the same issue?

Comment: Thank you very much it works great. may I know the cause.

Comment: When you pass a function as you were doing originally it loses any link to `this`. When the `WebSocket` executes your function later it uses itself as `this`, and the `WebSocket` class obviously has no `wshandler` property. Starting with ES6 the arrow function has been added as a way to work around that - an arrow function will preserve whatever `this` it has at the time, and make sure to restore it when it is invoked. So `arg => function(arg)` will invoke `function` with the correct `this`, in your case: `this` from `WebSocketSender`

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor change

```
this._self.wsHandler.onMessageReceived(jsonData)
```

to

```
this.wsHandler.onMessageReceived(jsonData)
```

the _self variable will only live in the constructor function, will not be available in other funciotns